# How to add all filtered elements in an state varaible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an array of objects containing users data stored in a `state varaible` and a table where I am displaying these users. I have a search field where a user can type name and search. Now my question is when a user types i want to search from these names and update the state variable and when user clears the input ,that time i want to show all users.in simple terms a search functionality.

```
const searchUsers = () => {
    items.filter((item) => {
      if (searchTerm === null) {
        setItems([...items]);
        return item;
      } else if (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)) {
        setItems([item]);
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Consider using a `.filter` within the JSX where the `items` array is being rendered. If you choose to update the `items` array using `setItems` and `.filter()` the items that would be filtered-out will also be lost from the state. Or, add prop to each `item` called (for example): `isShown` and update the prop based on the search criteria.

Comment: jsN00b : How can i achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook for this. You dont even need to update the state for filtered results.

```
const searchResults = useMemo(() => {
  if (!searchTerm) {
    return items;
  }

  return items?.filter((item) =>
    item?.toLowerCase()?.includes(searchTerm?.toLowerCase().trim())
  );
}, [items, searchTerm]);
```

You can directly use the `searchResults` while rendering your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const searchUsers = () => {
    if (searchTerm === "" || searchTerm === null) {
        setItems([...items])
        return
    }
    const results = items.filter((item) => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
    setItems(results)
}
```

1. If `searchTerm` is empty return all items and stop search
2. If `searchTerm` is not empty filter items based on `searchTerm`
3. Set the `results` as items

What you have to ensure as well is that `setItems` is not the setter for `items`. If you filter you will "remove" the items from the list which will cause elements to disappear when users searches something and goes back to an empty / or another search term. To fix this separate the state where all items are in and the state which items to display or filter in the JSX part.

The code could look like this:

```js
const items = ...
const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = setState(items)

const searchUsers = () => {
    if (searchTerm === "" || searchTerm === null) {
        setFilteredItems([...items])
        return
    }
    const results = items.filter((item) => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
    setFilteredItems(results)
}

return {filteredItems.map(item => <p>{item.title}</p>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var defaultitems = useMemo(_=>items)

const searchUsers = () => {
    if(!searchTerm) return setItems(defaultitems)
    var filtered = items.filter((item) => {
     if (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)) {
        return true
      }
      return false
    });
    setItems(filtered)
 };
```